# C++ FILE readInt function? (from a binary file)

Tags: c++, file, binary

Is there a function for FILE (fopen?) that allows me to just read one int from a binary file?

So far I'm trying this, but I'm getting some kind of error I can't see cause the program just crashes without telling me.

```
void opentest()
{
    FILE *fp = fopen("dqmapt.mp", "r");
    int i = 0;
    int j = 0;
    int k = 0;
    int * buffer;
    if (fp)
    {
        buffer = (int *) (sizeof(int));

        i = (int) fread(buffer,1, (sizeof(int)), fp);
        fscanf(fp, "%d", &j);
        fclose(fp);
    }

    printf("%d\n", i);
    printf("%d\n", j);
}
```

Comment: -1 for unclear question. No mention whether you want the int stored in binary for, as text, or other format. Also not a very useful question since it asks how to use a legacy C interface in C++. Use iostreams instead.

Comment: You don't have to vote him down because he didn't know the right question to ask.

Comment: Was "buffer = (int *) (sizeof(int));" supposed to be a call to malloc() or something?

Comment: If it's really in binary, William probably wants to make that "char buffer [sizeof(int)]".  And then reassembly the int from the bytes based on big/little endian ordering.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Now that you have changed your question, let me ask one. What is the format of the file you are trying to read?

For a binary file there are some changes required how you open the file:

```
/* C way */
FILE *fp = fopen("text.bin", "rb"); /* note the b; this is a compound mode */

/* C++ way */
std::ifstream ifs("test.txt", ios::in | ios::binary);
```

Reading in the contents is easy. But remember, your file has 2 integers at the begining -- width, height which determine how many more to read i.e. another width * height number of integers. So, your best bet is to read the first two integers first. You will need to use two buffers -- one for the width and height and then depending on their value another one to read the rest of the file. So, lets read in the first two integers:

```
char buf[ 2 * sizeof(int) ]; /* will store width and height */
```

Read in the two integers:

```
/* C way */
fread(buf, sizeof(int), 2, fp); /* the syntax changes, FILE pointer is last */

/* C++ way*/ 
ifs.read(buf, sizeof buf);
```

Now, the tricky part. You have to convert the stuff to double. This again depends on your system endianness -- whether a simple assignment works or whether a byte swapping is necessary. As another poster has pointed out `WriteInt()` writes integers in big-endian format. Figure out what system you are on. And then you can proceed further.

`FILE` is a C datastructure. It is included in C++ for C compatibility. You can do this:

```
/* The C way */
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void) {
   FILE *fp = fopen("test.txt", "r");
   int i = 0;
   if (fp) {
      fscanf(fp, "%d", &i);
      fclose(fp);
   }
   printf("%d\n", i);
}
```

You can use the `std::ifstream` thing to open a file for reading. You have to read in the contents using some other incantation to read the file contents and extract the desired information out of it yourself.

```
/* The C++ way */
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>

int main() {
   std::ifstream ifs("test.txt");
   int i = 0;
   if (ifs.good()) {
      ifs >> i;
   }
   std::cout << i << std::endl;
}
```

Note you can use the C style functions in C++ as well, though this is the least recommended way:

```
/* The C way in C++ */
#include <cstdio>
#include <cstdlib>

int main() {
   using namespace std;
   FILE *fp = fopen("test.txt", "r");
   int i = 0;
   if (fp) {
      fscanf(fp, "%d", &i);
      fclose(fp);
   }
   printf("%d\n", i);
}
```

[**Note:** Both examples assume you have a text file to read from]

Comment: Could you tell me how to do this with a binary file?

Comment: It's from Java's writeInt() method. It's just a simple map file. width, height, than a number of ints equal to (width * height)

Comment: I've made a lot of progress thanks to you, but it looks like I'll need to byte swap. I'm on windows XP home, if that helps.

Comment: Intel processors are typically little endian. So, yes a swap looks inevitable.

Answer (score 2):

Do you want to read a textual representation of an int? Then you can use fscanf, it's sort of the opposite of printf

```
int n;
if( fscanf(filePointer, "%d", &n) == 1 )
  // do stuff with n
```

If you want to read some binary data and treat it as an int, well that's going to depend how it was written in the first place.

---

I am not a Java programmer, so this is just based on what I've read in the [docs](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/api/java/io/DataOutputStream.html#writeInt(int)).

That said, it says

> Writes an int to the underlying output stream as four bytes, high byte first. If no exception is thrown, the counter written is incremented by 4.

So it's a big endian four byte integer. I don't know if it's two's complement or not, but that's probably a safe assumption (and can probably be found somewhere in the java docs/spec). Big endian is the same as network byte order, so you can use `ntohl` to convert it the endianness of your C++ platform. Beyond that, you just need to read the four bytes, which can be done with `fread`.

Comment: binary, written using Java's writeInt() method. The file is "¬í wl                                                                                          "

Answer (score 0):

Int represented as text or binary?

For text, use `fscanf`; for binary, use `fread`.